# How can I write this logic in JavaScript with less code?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of expenses where each expense has a category. Categories is also an array. I want to create an array that calculates the number of repeated category in expenses.

```
expenses = [
  {name: University, cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: Online course, cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: House, cat_id: 2}];

categories = [
  {id: 1, name: Education},
  {id: 2, name: Rent}];

catData = [];

categories.forEach((cat) => {
      catData.push(0);
});
```

I want an array called catData that will return this output `catData = [2, 1]`.
I did accomplish that using the logic below but I feel like it can be written in a better way using map or filter maybe?

```
expenses.forEach((exp) => {
   categories.forEach((cat, i) => {
      if (exp.cat_id == cat.id) {
        catData[i] += 1;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. There's no way to *significantly* shorten the code. You're pretty close to the bare minimum required already.

Comment: Where and how is catData defined? You can use reduce to create catData when defining it

Comment: `forEach` will always iterate the whole array. For better performance, you should replace it with for `for` loop, and `break` it after the element is found.

Comment: or use `.find()`

Comment: This code will probably crash, because `catData[i]` is undefined

Comment: I did define catData and gave it the same length as categories, I just didn't show it because my focus is on the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map and filter

```js
expenses = [
  {name: "University", cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: "Online course", cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: "House", cat_id: 2}];

categories = [
  {id: 1, name: "Education"},
  {id: 2, name: "Rent"}
]

const catData = categories.map(
  ({id}) => expenses.filter(({cat_id}) => id === cat_id).length
);

console.log(catData)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This may be "less code" as OP requested, but it is far less performant than a couple of simple for loops.

Comment: @404 Why not answer with your simple for loops and do let us know how poor the performance is  - perhaps Reem can tell us how many categories and how many expenses they expect, if a few thousands, it will not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a good compromise between lines of code and amount of operations is the following:

```js
const expenses = [
  { name: "University", cat_id: 1 },
  { name: "Online course", cat_id: 1 },
  { name: "House", cat_id: 2 }
];

const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: "Education" },
  { id: 2, name: "Rent" }
];

const catData = expenses.reduce((acc, current) => {
acc[current.cat_id -1] +=1
return acc;
}, new Array(categories.length).fill(0));
    
console.log(catData)
```

Comment: I like the fill. My reduce was too complex because I did not do a fill

Answer (score -2):

Use lodash groupBy:

```
const exp = _.groupBy(expenses, 'cat_id');
const catData = categories.map(({id}) => exp[id].length);
```

```js
const expenses = [
  {name: 'University', cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: 'Online course', cat_id: 1}, 
  {name: 'House', cat_id: 2}];

const categories = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Education'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rent'}
];


const exp = _.groupBy(expenses, 'cat_id');
console.log('GROUPED: ', exp);
const catData = categories.map(({id}) => exp[id].length);
console.log('CATEGORIES: ', catData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But this solution doesn't use less code. It loads an _entire library_. It uses MUCH more code.

Comment: @JeremyThille let me disagree with you. First, it's 2 code lines instead of 7. Second, using lodash is a good practice at common

Comment: I never used Lodash. I could always manipulate my arrays with `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.find()` or one of the many other methods. You can always disagree with me, you can't say your solution doesn't load 72 KB of minified code, so I really don't see how it uses _less_ code.

Comment: This does actually work and it is helpful. But is it a better practice to load a library or what I did originally?

Comment: @ReemObeid If a library helps and does not weight much, use it! Lodash (gziped) is just 20K (https://minime.stephan-brumme.com/lodash/4.2.0) which is neglectable, and has a lot of useful data manipulation routines. If you find my answer useful, please mark it as correct and upvote. Have a good day :)

Comment: Seriously, if the solution to iterate a couple of arrays is to import and use a third party library, I despair.